# Set Pandas MultiIndex index names on the same level as column name

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe:

[image]

Both the rows and columns are multi index.

The columns look like this:

```
MultiIndex(levels=[['1pm', '4pm'], ['% change', '2018', '2019']],
           codes=[[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1], [2, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0]],
           names=['', ''])
```

The rows look like this:

```
MultiIndex(levels=[['Live game', 'RedZone'], ['Sky Sports Action', 'Sky Sports Main Event', 'Sky Sports Mix', 'Total']],
           codes=[[0, 0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 3, 2, 3]],
           names=['Programme', 'Channel'])
```

I would like to set Programme and Channel to be on the same level as 2019, 2018 and % change by removing the gap between the data and the column names. Is this possible?

I'm looking to eventually output this to Excel, so I know I could shift the cells around eventually using openpyxl (or similar). But ideally it would be great if that could be done at this stage instead.

(I know the Total row and % change column aren't right, this is just dummy data)

Comment: @jezrael If I export the df to excel, cells C3:H3 are empty

Comment: I was on 0.24.2, have updated to 0.25.1 but still get those blank cells

Comment: yes, it is bug :(

Answer (score 0):

A workaround to fix this is to save the headers and table contents separately:

```
m1 = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['1pm', '4pm'], ['% change', '2018', '2019']], names=['', ''])
m2 = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['Live game', 'RedZone'], ['Sky Sports Action', 'Sky Sports Main Event', 'Sky Sports Mix', 'Total']], names=['Programme', 'Channel'])

df = pd.DataFrame(1, index=m2, columns=m1)
```

---

```
#https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/6618#issuecomment-382405067
writer = pd.ExcelWriter("test.xlsx")
headers = pd.DataFrame(df.columns.tolist()).T
#added index names for avoid lost ['Programme', 'Channel']
names =  pd.DataFrame([df.index.names], index=[headers.index.max()])
headers = pd.concat([names, headers], axis=1)

headers.to_excel(writer, header=False, index=False)
df.index.names = [None, None]
df.to_excel(writer, header=False, startrow=len(headers)-1)
writer.save()
```

Comment: This is very close, the only difference is rather than having a centered '1pm' title across the '2019', '2018', '% change' subtitles, '1pm' is repeated three times. The same with '4pm'

Comment: @OD1995 - But if write `MultiIndex` in pandas, this is expcted output. In `MultiIndex` are repeated `1pm`, `4pm`, only not diplayed.